# how to know if an element is already clicked jquery

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have a scenario in which i click an element say `#stationLink`. When I click it again I want to know if the element was already clicked. I had tried

```
var a=false;
$("#stationLink").click(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
     a = true
   });
   console.log(a);
});
```

I am getting `false` two times then only `true`.. I think i am missing something. Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do what you want (*including keeping a counter as i have seen you want in some comment*)

```
$("#stationLink").click(function(e){
   var $this = $(this);
   var clickCounter = $this.data('clickCounter') || 0;
   // here you know how many clicks have happened before the current one

   clickCounter += 1;
   $this.data('clickCounter', clickCounter);
   // here you know how many clicks have happened including the current one

});
```

Using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method you store the counter with the DOM element, and this way you can apply the same handler to multiple elements, since each one will have its own counter.

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gfJj6/1/

Answer (score 4):

You could add an attribute you could check:

```
$("#stationLink").click(function(){
   $(this).attr("hasBeenClicked", "true");
});
```

I don't like using a global var to keep whether this  item has been clicked for the simple reason that if you have to keep track of more than one item then it can be a little messy.  I prefer the ass class or attribute as you can see on the element whether it has been clicked

Answer (score 3):

This version records the number of clicks:

```
$("#stationLink").click(function() {
    var clickCount = $(this).data('clickCount') || 0;

    if (clickCount > 0) {
        // clicked `clickCount` times
    }

    $(this).data('clickCount', clickCount + 1);
});
```

To reset the click count use

```
$("#stationLink").data('clickCount', 0);
```

Comment: is there any way to know how many times has the element been clicked?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're actually binding another click handler to the element the first time you click it. Just remove that handler.

```
var clicked = false;
$("#stationLink").click(function(){
    clicked = true
    //Code to toggle if required. 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
$('#stationLink').click(function(){
   $(this).data('clicked', true);
});

console.log($(this).data('clicked'));
```

I think this is the method most used by jquery ui.

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a class named .chosen or .x_visited to it

```
$("#stationLink").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("x_visited")
}
```

Then you can check against that with `$("#stationLink").hasClass('x_visited');` for example

Answer (score 1):

```
var stationLink_clicked = false;

$("#stationLink").click(function(){
   console.log('Already clicked? ' + stationLink_clicked);
   /* do stuff */

   stationLink_clicked = true;
});
```